# How does one find a specific package to install with YUM?

Tags: apache, yum

I want to install Apache Solr on my linux machine, and am wondering if I can install it with yum.  `yum list` prints all available packages, but it's impossible to read through thousands of these to find the right install, especially considering a package could be named virtually anything.

Is there a better way to find out if a particular package is available with yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options (since they both tend to return different results)

```
yum search solr
yum list | grep solr
```

I see only the PHP plugin on my machine, but I'm using an older release.

Need even more, you can do a filename match on things with solr in them:

```
yum provides */*solr*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum search solr
```

If it doesn't find it, you might need to add more repositories.